# Regex to allow PhoneNumber with country code

Tags: javascript, c#, regex

I need a regex to validate a phone number (With country code )which shall follow the below conditions

```
1 - There should be at max 4 digits in between + and - . 
2 - Phone number shall be a combination of +,- and digits
3 - 0 shall not be allowed after - 
4 - After - only 10 digits are allowed
```

E.g

```
    1 - +91234-1234567 - Fail (1st Condition fails)
    2 - +9123-1234567  - Pass 
    3 - +               - Fail (2nd condition fails)
    4 - -               - Fail (2nd condition fails)
    5 - 91234545555     - Fail (2nd condition fails)
    6 - +91-012345      - Fail (3rd Condition fails)
    7 - +91-12345678910 - Fail (4th condition fails)
```

Please help me in this .Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
\+\d{1,4}-(?!0)\d{1,10}\b
```

Breakdown:

```
\+                        Match a literal +
\d{1,4}                   Match between 1 and 4 digits inclusive
-                         Match a literal -
(?!                       Negative lookahead, fail if
  0                       this token (literal 0) is found
)
\d{1,10}                  Match between 1 and 10 digits inclusive
\b                        Match a word boundary
```

Demo (with your examples)

```js
var phoneRegexp = /\+\d{1,4}-(?!0)\d{1,10}\b/g,
  tests = [
    '+91234-1234567',
    '+9123-1234567',
    '+',
    '-',
    '91234545555',
    '+91-012345',
    '+91-12345678910'
  ],
  results = [],
  expected = [false, true, false, false, false, false, false];

results = tests.map(function(el) {
  return phoneRegexp.test(el);
});

for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
  document.getElementById('result').textContent += (results[i] === expected[i]) + ', ';
}
```

```html
<p id="result"></p>
```

Comment: There is not a tool for generating regexps beyond knowledge and learning that I am aware of. For most regexps I generally find a well known, well tested regexp for matching known formats.

Comment: Is there a benefit to use a lookahead instead of `\+\d{1,4}-[1-9]\d{,9}\b` ?

Comment: @vivek Try it and see, don't see why not.

Comment: @ZoharPeled I suspect that `\+\d{1,4}-[1-9]\d{1,9}\b` would execute faster. I used lookahead because it closer matches the semantics of the requirement *"0 shall not be allowed after - "*

Answer (score 1):

In C# you can go with:

```
public class RegexTelephoneNumber
{
    public void Test()
    {
        Regex regex = new Regex(@"^\+\d{1,4}-[1-9]\d{0,9}$");

        Trace.Assert(MatchTest(regex, "+91234-1234567") == false);
        Trace.Assert(MatchTest(regex, "+9123-1234567") == true);
        Trace.Assert(MatchTest(regex, "+") == false);
        Trace.Assert(MatchTest(regex, "-") == false);
        Trace.Assert(MatchTest(regex, "91234545555") == false);
        Trace.Assert(MatchTest(regex, "+91-012345") == false);
        Trace.Assert(MatchTest(regex, "+91-12345678910") == false);

        Trace.Assert(MatchTest(regex, "++91234-1234567") == false);
        Trace.Assert(MatchTest(regex, "+91234-1234567+") == false);
        Trace.Assert(MatchTest(regex, "aa+91234-1234567+bb") == false);
        Trace.Assert(MatchTest(regex, "+91-12") == true);
    }

    private bool MatchTest(Regex regex, string text)
    {
        Match match = regex.Match(text);
        return match.Success;
    }
}
```

Regex explained:

```
^        - start anchor
\+       - character '+'
\d{1,4)  - any digit repeating min 1 and max 4 times
-        - character '-'
[1-9]    - any digit apart from 0, taking place exactly once
\d{0,9}  - any digit repeating min 0 and max 9 times
$        - end anchor
```