# RegEx for phoneNumber with optional CountryCode

Tags: javascript, regex

I am using the `\+\d{1,4}\s?-\s?(?!0)\d{1,10}\b` to execute the below test cases

```
1 - There should be at max 4 digits in between + and - . 
2 - Phone number shall be a combination of +,- and digits
3 - 0 shall not be allowed after - 
4 - After - only 10 digits are allowed
5 - Space allowed after and before -
```

E.g

```
    1 - +91234-1234567 - Fail (1st Condition fails)
    2 - +123-1234567  - Pass 
    3 - +               - Fail (2nd condition fails)
    4 - -               - Fail (2nd condition fails)
    5 - 91234545555     - Fail (2nd condition fails)
    6 - +21-012345      - Fail (3rd Condition fails)
    7 - +91-12345678910 - Fail (4th condition fails)
    8 - +32 - 12345678  - Pass (Space allowed before and after -)
```

Now i want to make some part ( Country code  +91- ) as optional to execute the below test cases

```
E.g.    
     1)12345678 - Pass (Since we are making country code(+91-) as optional)
     2)+1233433 - Fail 
     3)+91-1233333- pass
```

To achive this i did the following changes in the regex `/(\+\d{1,4}\s?-\s?)?(?!0)\d{1,10}\b/` but with the above updated regex its allowing the following also

```
     1)-123455
     2)+123333
```

I want to make the whole thing as optional (+XX-) not the part of it . 
Please help me in it . Thanks in advance.

Comment: I feel like I've answered this before...

Comment: @jdphenix. Yes you have answered it but now it needs some more changes as  mentioned (Making country code optional) . Please help me to achieve the same .

Comment: @vivek: Will something like this do: https://regex101.com/r/xN5pQ9/1 ? Instead of making the whole 1st part optional, add an alternative for `+91`: `(?:-\s*\+91\s*-|\+\d{1,4}\s?-\s?)`

Comment: @stribizhev I tried this with  regex you have given but its failing .
var phoneReg = new RegExp(/(?:-\s*\+91\s*-|\+\d{1,4}\s?-\s?)/); phoneReg.test("12"); 
 Anyway it is not only +91 . It could be any number .

Comment: @vivek: You tested against a part of my regex. Also, you are using a RegExp constructor notation, then, you need to double slashes (full JS RegeExp declaration code `var phoneReg = new RegExp("(?:-\\s*\\+\\d{2}\\s*-|\\+\\d{1,4}\\s?-\\s?)(?!0)\\d{1,10}\\b");`). See another demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/mrxafevc/

Comment: Removing `C#` tag from the question, since the language used is JavaScript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
/^(?:\+\d{1,4}\s?-\s?)?(?!0)\d{1,10}\b/
```

Breakdown:

```
^                                  Assert at beginning of string 
(?:\+\d{1,4}\s?-\s?)?              Only changed to group country code
                                   and make it match 0 - 1 times.
and the rest                       Otherwise no changes.
```

The key changes are the string boundary assertion and the optional country code group.

Comment: What if the phone number string comes inside a larger string?

Comment: I am assuming from the previous interaction at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29586983/regex-to-allow-phonenumber-with-country-code that this is not a problem. Obviously, this would not match a phone number inside a string.

Comment: @jdphenix Thanks .. It wont come in larger string . But the above returns true for "\91123" and "1-91123". If - is there then + shall be there and vice versa . Can you please update the regex accordingly ?